# i want to get the value of count which is persent in app.js into counter.js i am new to react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a small application in reactjs,
I have two files app and counter
this is my appfile

```
    export default function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const handleEvent = () => {
    return setCount(count + 1);
        };

 return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleEvent} 
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After clicking on increment the value of count increases

i want the count value in the below counterjs file
i  don't know how to achieve

This is my counterfile

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";

export default function Counter() {
  let counters = [
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {counters.map((num) => (
        <table key={num.id}>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>value</th>
            <th>qunatity</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{num.id}</td>
            <td>{num.value}</td>

            <td><App /></td>

            <td>{num.value * 1}</td>//here i want to use the count here
          </tr>
        </table>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please add the issue or problem that you faced?

Comment: I want the count value in counterjs file. I want use it in table

Answer (score 0):

You can lift the state from the `App` component to the `Counter` component. This technique is called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

`App.jsx`:

```js
export default function App(props) {

  const handleEvent = () => {
    return props.onIncrement();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleEvent}>
        Increment
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Counter.jsx`:

```js
import App from "./App";

export default function Counter() {

  const [counters, setCounters] = useState(() => [
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 },
  ]);
  
  const onIncrementListeners = counters.map((_, i) => {
    return () => {
      setCounters((counters) => [
        ...counters.slice(0, i),
        { ...counters[i], value: counters[i].value + 1 },
        ...counters.slice(i + 1),
      ]);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {counters.map((num, i) => (
        <table key={num.id}>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>value</th>
            <th>qunatity</th>
            <th>price</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{num.id}</td>
            <td>{num.value}</td>

            <td><App onIncrement={onIncrementListeners[i]} /></td>

            <td>{num.value * 1}</td>//here i want to use the count here
          </tr>
        </table>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE ANSWER                                                                                                         "<td><App /></td>" this one which is not working if i remove the import in counterjs file is there any other way

Comment: @bhagyaraj028 I have updated my answer. I misunderstood your question before.